# GPG error for command apt-get update

Tags: cuda, gnupg

First of all I tried to install cuda-9.0 with ([source: tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu))

```
# Add NVIDIA package repository
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update

# Install CUDA and tools. Include optional NCCL 2.x
sudo apt install cuda9.0 cuda-cublas-9-0 cuda-cufft-9-0 cuda-curand-9-0 \
    cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusparse-9-0 libcudnn7=7.2.1.38-1+cuda9.0 \
    libnccl2=2.2.13-1+cuda9.0 cuda-command-line-tools-9-0

# Optional: Install the TensorRT runtime (must be after CUDA install)
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvinfer4=4.1.2-1+cuda9.0
```

which didn't worked so I removed with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cuda
```

Then I was trying to install cuda-9.0 with apt-get install cuda-9.0, which failed but after that apt-get update gave me error:

```
Err:22 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Get:24 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,136 B]
Err:24 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Get:25 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,129 B]
Err:25 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-176-local-patch-4  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-3  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552 NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
E: The repository 'https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```